# How to start nodejs with custom params from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to start nodeJS with additional command line parameters?

like:

--harmony_generators
 --harmony_arrow_functions

UPD:

workaround for now:

1. create **.bat** (windows) file with:

   - *{{path-to-node}}*\node.exe --harmony_generators --harmony_arrow_functions %*
2. add path to your **.bat** file as source of **runtimeExecutable** in **.\settings\launch.json**
3. profit :)

Comment: Visual Studio code 0.3.0 has fixed this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the preview version of VSCode it is not yet possible to pass arguments to node from the launch.json. But the workaround mentioned above works fine.
I have created a bug on our side and will make sure it’s fixed with the next release.

Andre Weinand,
Visual Studio Code

---

*Update:*

The fix is in VSCode since v0.3 with this in `.settings/launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        ...

        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": [],

        ...
```

So to e.g. run Node.js (v0.12) with ES6 support use `"runtimeArgs": ["--harmony"],`

Comment: this sadly is not working for me. i got node version v0.12.4 and vs code version 0.5.0. [Here](http://pastebin.com/w6KmWK9n) is my launch.json config. What am i missing?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? The launch.json looks fine.

Comment: When the code hits the first generator fn i get the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`. and btw it does not stop on entry. i am pressing the green play button in the debug pane with the `Launch app.js` config selected.

Comment: Bear in mind that you **MUST** pass the arguments with **no spaces** at all in the argument string. So this is valid: `"runtimeArgs": ["--harmony"]` , but this is **NOT** valid: `"runtimeArgs": [" --harmony "]`
The second one will result in `Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/project/ --harmony '`

Answer (score 10):

In My case I was running this command and parameter:
node app.js read --title="SomeTitle"

and to solve that i used this:

```
"args": [
            "read",
            "\--\--title\=='SomeTitle'"
        ]
```

and the output was this:

node --inspect=10398 --debug-brk app.js read --title='Title'

That suited me well.

The suggestion to use runtimeArgs don't worked for me because its passed "before" invoking my app.js.

Comment: `runtimeArgs` is for node arguments, `args` is for script arguments.

Answer (score 6):

With the current Versión **1.36.1** you can add args to your **launch.json**
Example:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "args":["my-url=http://192.168.1.24:8984/api/", "port=3000"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In your node app you can capture Args:

```js
 process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) 
 {
   console.log(val);
 }
```

Now you can run your **Visual Studio Code debug** and see how args are showed

If you run the App **from console** it should be like this:

```js
node index.js my-url=http://192.168.1.24:8984/api/ port=3000
```

The output in both cases is:

```sh
my-url=http://192.168.1.24:8984/api/
port=3000
```

Comment: But if you need it before the path (like node -r esm index.js), then it does not work since it places arguments at the end

Answer (score 1):

Edit `./settings/launch.json` (debug menu > gear icon)

There's an `args` entry you can edit

Comment: the only way I can see for now is create .bat (windows) file and add manually all needed params and then define it in ./settings/launch.json as runtimeExecutable but that looks wired.