# the --harmony flag in the args parameter seems not to work

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

the --harmony flag for node in the args parameter seems not to work. I can't use fat array functions.
Here part of `lounch.json`

```
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch app.js",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "./app.js",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": ["--harmony"],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

Is there a way to fix the problem myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "args" parameter is not for the node process, but rather arguments for the app.
I was confused by this myself, the documentation should make this clearer.

See this question for a workaround: [How to start nodejs with custom params from vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968919/how-to-start-nodejs-with-custom-params-from-vscode)