# Converting debug configuration between WebStorm and VSCode

Tags: node.js, webstorm, visual-studio-code, node-debugger

I recently changed from a development role to a QA role. In setting up the QA project, the instructions I have give configuration requirements for WebStorm. I however much prefer to use VSCode.

I'm trying to convert WebStorm debug configuration options to VSCode. I have listed what I think the equivalent option for launch.json based upon the values I was given.

WEBSTORM => VSCODE

1. Node interpreter => runtimeExecutable
2. Node parameters => args
3. Working directory => cwd
4. JavaScript file => program
5. Application parameters => runtimeArgs
6. Environment variables => env

Usually when running Node.js programs I only have one set of parameters that I can access via the `process.argv` array.

What is the difference between the 2 parameter types and when in the debug/run process are they used? Are they accessed differently in Node.js?

Answer (score 2):

> Node parameters => args Application parameters => runtimeArgs

I'd say - just the contrary. **args** in VSCode are arguments passed to Node application being run, the ones you normally retrieve via `process.argv[2], ... process.argv[n]`. These are **Application parameters** in WebStorm.

**runtimeArgs** are paremeters passed to **runtimeExecutable** - in generic case, it can be any executable available on the `$PATH` (for example 'npm', 'mocha', 'gulp', etc.). But, when migrating **Node.js** run configuration from WebStorm, it would be **Node parameters**

See [What is the difference between args and runtimeArgs in VSCode's launch.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207740/what-is-the-difference-between-args-and-runtimeargs-in-vscodes-launch-json), [How to start nodejs with custom params from vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968919/how-to-start-nodejs-with-custom-params-from-vscode)

For more information about Node.js parameters, see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html