# VS Code debug with --experimental-modules flag

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, es6-modules, vscode-debugger

I can run my node.js application with `es6` modules with the `--experimental-modules` flag as follows:

```
node --experimental-modules ./bin/www
```

How can I do the same when debuggging the application from VS Code, which uses the launch.json configuration file?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Program",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the `"program"` key you can pass the needed flag in `"args"` before you pass it your module.

```sh
node --experimental-modules ./myModule
```

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "run module",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--experimental-modules", "${workspaceFolder}/myModule"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I only learned this last week trying to do the same thing with a Python program.

Comment: Nice one. In a few months, future-me will be very confused trying figure out how this config works, but that's his problem.

Answer (score 4):

The [**official guidance**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_how-do-i-debug-ecmascript-modules) is to use the [**`runtimeArgs`** attribute](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes) like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "node",
    "runtimeArgs": ["--experimental-modules"],
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www"
}
```

Which will run the following terminal command:

```bash
node.exe --experimental-modules .\bin\www
```

**See Also**: [How to start nodejs with custom params from vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29968919/1366033)